# recognizing a date in the form: 03/02 for February 3 , For simplicity, we consider that each month is made up of 30 days

Tags: java, for-loop, compilation, switch-statement, automaton

this is the code :

```
package Tp2;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EX2_Date_forme {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("give a string or (exit) to leave : ");
            String input = sc.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                Date(input);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Date(String input) {
        int len = input.length();
        int state = 0;
        int tracker = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            boolean c_isBetween_zero_in_AndNine = Character.getNumericValue(c) >= 0 && Character.getNumericValue(c) <= 9;
            boolean c_isBetween_zero_out_AndNine = Character.getNumericValue(c) > 0 && Character.getNumericValue(c) <= 9;
            switch (state) {

                case 0:
                    if (c == '0'){
                        state = 1;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else if (c == '1' || c == '2'){
                        state = 2;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else if (c == '3'){
                        state = 3;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (c_isBetween_zero_out_AndNine) {
                        state = 4;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (c_isBetween_zero_in_AndNine){
                        state = 4;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (c == '0') {
                        state = 4;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (c == '/') {
                        state = 5;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (c == '0'){
                        state = 6;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else if (c == '1'){
                        state = 7;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if (c_isBetween_zero_out_AndNine){
                        state = 8;
                        tracker++;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    if (c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2'){
                        tracker++;
                        state = 8;
                    }
                    else System.out.println("error");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (tracker == len) System.out.println("in the language");
                    else
                        System.out.println("error");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We want to recognize a date in the form:
03/02 for February 3, limited to the current year.

For simplicity, we consider that each month is made up
of 30 days.

When, for example, I type "01/01" in debug mode, everything works as expected until the last iteration where i=4, len=5, and state=8. However, the for loop doesn't continue to enter case 8.

i expected to see the "in the langage message" but I got no result

it worked when i added this after the loop and it worked :

```
    if (state == 8 && tracker == len) {
        System.out.println("in the language");
    } else {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
```

but i want it to enter the case number 8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what your code is doing. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should explain how your code works. It seems an implementation of a state machine. You should explain the design in your question. We don't know what the states are or why it should enter one. Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve validation in this code?  If your code is only about validating a date then there are far simpler ways to do this. If this is what you are looking for then why aren't you doing this with a date formatter? Important to note that if you then need to include special alternative routes for February and 31 day months, this code has the potential to become so complex that it becomes unmanageable.  You are probably better off identifying 28, 29, 30 and 31 day month(s),  calculating the full day  `n[0] * 10  + n[1]`  and then checking if they fall in range. Probably...